# PHP include doesn't work into of a symbolic directory

Tags: php, mysql, include, symlink

I have a problem that I am unable to resolve.

I have two files: `conexion.php` and `query.php`

The `conexion.php` file creates a connection to the database in the variable `$link`. The code works fine.

The query.php file queries the database using the connection created (`$link`).

I use:

```
include('conexion.php');
```

The files are in the same directory. If I copy the conexion.php code into query.php works fine, but if I use "include" or "require" it doesn't work.

Because I use SVN, the directory that contains my website in Apache is a "symbolic link" to a copy of SVN repository. If I copy the files to a real directory of Apache, the files work fine, but I need work with SVN.

Now, I describe the directory Structure:

Website in Apache: `/var/www/website/`

SVN copy: `/home/svn/backend`

Symbolic link: `/var/www/website/backend --> /home/svn/backend`

```
$> ls /home/svn/backend
conexion.php
query.php


http://localhost/website/backend
```

Comment: Anything of interrest in the error log?

Comment: The FIRST thing you should be checking is whether your include_path contains '.' I don't believe your problem is anything to do with symbolic links (assuming we're talking about a POSIX filesystem and not Microsoft shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

You may find specifying the full path with `__DIR__` fixes it because you're referencing `query.php` from a different place:

```
include __DIR__.'/conexion.php';
```